# Paste values of scalar in observation after bootstrap

Tags: stata, scalar

I need help to paste bootstrapped coefficients and their lower and
upper 95% CI in new variables to produce graphs.

I tried the code below. It looks like scalars are retrieved with
success, but I am not able to paste them into specific observations
when using `replace`.

```
clear all
forvalues j=0/1{
    foreach l in P2 P3 P4 {
        use `l'_per_`j', clear
        set seed 1
        reg estimate xaxis
        predict yhat
        gen yhat_bs=yhat
        gen ll_95per=.
        gen ul_95per=.
        local N = _N
        foreach i in 1/11 { //number of time periods to be predicted
            bootstrap pred=(_b[_cons] + _b[xaxis]*`i'), reps(1000) seed(1): reg
            estimate xaxis
            matrix b=e(b)
            scalar sb=b[1,1]
            matrix ci_normal=e(ci_normal)
            local par=b[1,1] //coefficient bootstrap
            local ll=ci_normal[1,1] //lower CI 95%
            local ul=ci_normal[2,1] //upper CI 95%
            replace yhat_bs=`par' if xaxis==`i' 
            replace ll_95per=`ll' if xaxis==`i' 
            replace ul_95per=`ul' if xaxis==`i'
        }
        save `l'_per_`j'_lin_trend, replace
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `foreach i in 1/11` is wrong here. So far as Stata is concerned this is a list with one item `1/11` which will not be expanded. So, when Stata gets to the line

```
replace yhat_bs=`par' if xaxis==`i'
```

that will become, the one time this loop is executed,

```
replace <stuff> if xaxis==1/11
```

Now that's legal: 1/11 is a fraction that Stata will calculate. But you have no values of `xaxis` that are equal to that fraction, so nothing gets replaced.

You want `foreach i of num 1/11` or even better `forval i = 1/11`. Here is a rewriting of your code. I also cut out the unnecessary middle macros and some other stuff that appears unnecessary, but I have not tested this.

```
clear all
forvalues j = 0/1 {
    foreach l in P2 P3 P4 {
        use `l'_per_`j', clear
        set seed 1
        reg estimate xaxis
        predict yhat
        gen yhat_bs = yhat 
        gen ll_95per = .
        gen ul_95per = .

        forval i = 1/11 { //number of time periods to be predicted
            bootstrap pred=(_b[_cons] + _b[xaxis]*`i'), reps(1000) seed(1): reg             estimate xaxis
            matrix b = e(b)
            matrix ci_normal = e(ci_normal)
            replace yhat_bs = b[1,1] if xaxis == `i' 
            replace ll_95per = ci_normal[1,1] if xaxis == `i' 
            replace ul_95per = ci_normal[2,1] if xaxis == `i'
        }
        save `l'_per_`j'_lin_trend, replace
    }
}
```